# Opencv (opencv-contrib) is changing the color of image after using object detection module (cv2.dnn.readNet)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision

I trained a YoloV4 model and used `opencv-contrib` because `openCv` does not support `YoloV4` yet. You can use it with `yolov3`. Thee are 2 problems with the code:

1. When the final image is seen using `cv2.imshow`, it shoes the traingle as **Yellow** instead of blue. I need to extract that triangle and pass to some other Network so I can not use the yellow image.
2. It is giving results only and only when we use `scale=1/255.` else, it provides bad results. Why is that?

I want to ask why is it changing the colours and how can I prevent it? I know that it corresponds to `BGR` format of `opencv` but how can it be resolved.

```
import requests
import numpy as np 
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import cv2


CONFIDENCE_THRESHOLD = 0.5
NMS_THRESHOLD = 0.5
COLORS = [(0, 255, 255), (255, 255, 0), (0, 255, 0), (255, 0, 0)]

net = cv2.dnn.readNet("./yolov4-obj_best_1_class.weights", "./yolov4-custom_1_class.cfg")
model = cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(net)
model.setInputParams(size=(416, 416),scale=1/255.)


url = 'https://instasolv1.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/QuestionBank/5e9ad4b1e1c473f2bce0e4ff/crop_image.png' # Check original image 
response = requests.get(url)

img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
classes, scores, boxes = model.detect(img_array, CONFIDENCE_THRESHOLD, NMS_THRESHOLD)


box = boxes[0]

(x, y) = (box[0], box[1])
(w, h) = (box[2], box[3])

cv2.rectangle(img_array, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0,255,0), 2)
text = "Text"
cv2.putText(img_array, text, (x, y - 5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
    0.5, (255,0,255), 2)

cv2.imshow("Show",img_array) # given result has yellow triangle
cv2.waitKey()  
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: `img` is RGB ordered, seeing it was loaded using Pillow. So, `img_array` is just "falsely" presented in the `cv2.imshow` window. It's just a visualization thing here. If you further process `img_array`, e.g. feeding to some other net, you still have a RGB ordered image. If you want to have a proper RGB preview, consider using `imshow` from `matplotlib.pyplot`.

Comment: @HansHirse Thanks. That's what I thought and cropped the image using Numpy Only and passed in the results. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following code:

```
import requests
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import cv2


CONFIDENCE_THRESHOLD = 0.5
NMS_THRESHOLD = 0.5
COLORS = [(0, 255, 255), (255, 255, 0), (0, 255, 0), (255, 0, 0)]

#net = cv2.dnn.readNet("./yolov4-obj_best_1_class.weights", "./yolov4-custom_1_class.cfg")
#model = cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(net)
#model.setInputParams(size=(416, 416),scale=1/255.)


#url = 'https://instasolv1.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/QuestionBank/5e9ad4b1e1c473f2bce0e4ff/crop_image.png' # Check original image
#response = requests.get(url)

#img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
img=Image.open('RGBY_example.png')
#classes, scores, boxes = model.detect(img_array, CONFIDENCE_THRESHOLD, NMS_THRESHOLD)
img_array_original=np.array(img)

img_array=img_array_original
#img_array=cv2.cvtColor(img_array_original,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

#box = boxes[0]
box=[100,100,50,60]

(x, y) = (box[0], box[1])
(w, h) = (box[2], box[3])



cv2.rectangle(img_array, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0,255,0), 2)
text = "Text"
cv2.putText(img_array, text, (x, y - 5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
    0.5, (255,0,255), 2)

cv2.imshow("Show",img_array) # given result has yellow triangle
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

...and you get erratic colors:

[image]

...as a result.

To solve that, remove # from line 26:

[image]

...and you will see the correct colors. This way you see the idea, and can handle whatever color-spaces with your images in future.

Comment: The example image RGB_example.png can be found from https://github.com/mih-ai/tukimateriaalia/blob/77e7dbc5c6d8c4209177d294fffef56c9c345482/RGBY_example.png

Answer (score 0):

Answer for question n:o 2 "It is giving results only and only when we use scale=1/255. else, it provides bad results. Why is that?"

The required input scale for the inputs of the DNN is from 0 to 1. In RGB-images each pixel color value is between 0 and 255. Thus, to preprocess the image for the DNN each pixel value is multiplied by 1/225.